# Differences between test program documentation APIs (cc, pp, group, #)

Tags: origen-sdk

Looking at the [Origen test program documentation creation guide](http://origen-sdk.org/origen/guides/program/doc/) I still had a couple questions:

1. What is the difference between 'cc' and using comments (#) before a test?
2. Is 'pp' only a documentation grouper (i.e. not the same as :group)?
3. When using the Flow :group method, is a documentation group automatically created?

thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The flow files are parsed for (#) comments and automatically attached to the following tests, but interface files are not. The `cc` method provides a mechanism to supply test descriptions from interface files. Probably in flow files you can use either.
2. Yes, `pp` should only create a group for the purposes of documentation, but not in the test program flow.
3. Yes, any test program flow group will be represented in documentation without the need to use `pp`.