# Adding dynamic content to test flow comments

Tags: origen-sdk

As a related question to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47516005/differences-between-test-program-documentation-apis-cc-pp-group), is it possible to add in dynamic content to test flow comments?  I see that the [Origen test program docs](http://origen-sdk.org/origen/guides/program/doc/) say that the comment directly preceding a test is added to the test program documentation.  That works fine for flows where the owner knows the name of the test, versus iterative flows where the test name is made up of many variables like this:

```
hsio_loopback loopback_type: test_type, loopback_mode: lpbk_mode, protocol_mode: mode, speed: speed, cond: voltage
```

Perhaps being able to use ERB in the comments would work?

thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not currently a method you can call to inject dynamic comments, and I don't think we really want to introduce an erb parsing stage.

I don't think adding such a method would be very easy to add either.

An enhancement I could see would be to add the ability to put regular string interpolation logic within comments, and then we can have the comment parser eval the comment strings.

This would come with one big caveat though: since the comments are parsed (and would be eval'd) out side of the flow execution, it would not be able to evaluate any local variables embedded within the comments.

i.e. this would not work, since the `i` is a local variable:

```rb
dut.srams.each_with_index do |sram, i|

  # Testing SRAM #{i}
  test "sram", instance: i

end
```

Something like this, would work though since it is injecting a global variable which will be accessible later when it comes to parsing/evaluating the comments, but may be of less use to you:

```rb
# Testing one of #{dut.srams.size} SRAMs
test "sram", instance: i
```

I think to do what you really want, we would need to support this, but it would just be more work that you would probably have to roll up your sleaves for:

```rb
dut.srams.each_with_index do |sram, i|

  cc "Testing SRAM #{i}"
  test "sram", instance: i

end
```